# Android - Set Spacing between Buttons in GridLayout programmatically

Tags: java, android

How can I change the spacing between the buttons, so there is no Space anymore?
They are created programmatically in a GridLayout.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jM3fY.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

You can remove spaces using the following code:

```
gridLayout = (GridLayout) findViewById(R.id.gridlayout);
gridLayout.setUseDefaultMargins(false);
gridLayout.setAlignmentMode(GridLayout.ALIGN_BOUNDS);
gridLayout.setRowOrderPreserved(false);
```